# My desktop keeps disconnecting and refusing to connect to wifi

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, desktop-computer

I use an HP ENVY desktop and Windows 10, I’ve had it for about two years now and since i got it it would randomly disconnect from internet but the issue was usually solved after a quick reset.
My issue now is that just reseting or unplugging my computer isn’t working anymore. When I click on the quick settings to check, the wifi widget has completely disappeared, and is not visible in network and internet settings either.
I’ve already made sure that I have everything I need updated, but nothing seems to work. My computer is also a bit far from my wifi router, so I cannot use an ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already:

1. Used DISM and SFC to fix OS files.
2. Used the Windows Internet Connections Troubleshooter.

Then: confirm that it is definitely *not* and OS/driver issue by booting from a live USB device, such as [Ubuntu Live](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/).

3. If you *cannot access* WiFi from the OS on USB, then look to hardware, e.g., a loose connector on the WiFi card. Download the Envy shop manual to do this, or look for directions on the web. An alternative would be to buy a USB WiFi adapter ("dongle"), sold for US$5 or more, e.g., [this with antenna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08G8QZRKG).
4. If you *can access* WiFi while running from USB, then you've confirmed the issue is in Windows and/or the WiFi drivers. Since piecemeal repair hasn't worked, *make a disk image in case something goes wrong*, and *then* reinstall Windows, choosing to keep files.